Can someone help me understand why my code is timing out?
I'm trying to deploy a Hugging Face model with SageMaker, all from a Google Colab notebook.
I'm trying to follow this RAG tutorial on YouTube. The instructor seems to be leaving out an important part of the basic setup process. His code does not make any reference to tokens or how to make everything talk to each other.
I've followed the setup in the video, and copied the code directly from SageMaker. When that didn't run, I spent several hours troubleshooting and eventually discovered that I have to declare my role directly. I can't rely on the code they gave in the link above. Here's what I have:
sagemaker.Session(boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY', 
                                        aws_secret_access_key='MY_SECRET_KEY', 
                                        aws_session_token=None, region_name='us-west-1', 
                                        botocore_session=None, profile_name=None))

role = 'arn:aws:iam::MY_ID:role/sagemaker_execution_role'

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1',
    'SM_NUM_GPUS': json.dumps(8),
    'HUGGING_FACE_HUB_TOKEN': 'MY_TOKEN'
}

assert hub['HUGGING_FACE_HUB_TOKEN'] != '<MY_TOKEN, "You have to provide a token."

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    image_uri=get_huggingface_llm_image_uri("huggingface",version="2.0.2"),
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge",
    container_startup_health_check_timeout=2100,
  )

This code times out every time. I've tried using different instance types, and that doesn't help. Why is this timing out? Thank you.
